# Javascript - meaning of `$("a[href*='video']")`

Tags: javascript, css

I have this line of code in which I can't explain to myself this `$("a[href*='video']")` line of code. There is just too much mystery in it.

```
$("a[href*='video']").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    playVideo(id);
});

function playVideo(id) {
    var $video = $(id + " video")[0];
    $video.play();

    $(".close").click(function() {
        $video.pause();
        $video.currentTime = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: It means get all the `a` tags; if the `href`attribute of the current `a` tag contains the word `video` get the `href` of that attribute and pass it to the `playVideo` function, which will then find an element with an `id` equals to that string + the word "video" and then play said video.

Comment: jQuery selectors are [thoroughly documented](http://api.jquery.com/), and most of them are CSS selectors, which are also thoroughly documented in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors).

Comment: As it turns out this site holds a large portion of the answer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("a[href*='video']")`

It's a jQuery [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). This will return `Array` of all links `<a>` elements, whose href contains `video` in the link.

`<a href="http://google.com/video/abc">`

like this link contains video in url .. so, it will get selected.

Comment: * of `<a>` elements containing `video`in their `href`attribute. In this context, link can be ambiguous.

Comment: *"this will return Array..."* No, it won't. It will return a jQuery object, which is *like* an array, but it isn't an array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed ! Its has type of `object` but, can be used as an array ... `$("a[href*='video']")[0]` will return first element from the object.

Comment: @atulquest93: No, it can't be used as an array. It supports *some* array operations, yes, but not all. So calling it an array when it isn't an array is misleading.

Comment: So ok I get the array/object. What does keyword `this` in `var id = $(this).attr("href");` do then? I understand that this will assign a value to a variable `id` but which one from the array will it choose? Does `this` keyword actually mean the href link with video string  that we clicked?

Comment: @71GA it depends on value of `this` .. if you are inside an `forEach` loop  then `this` will refer to current value .. so after loop id will contain href value from last element of array.. or otherwise it will contain reference to previous array.

Answer (score 1):

What this selector does is first target all anchors, the bracket notation then targets an attribute of those elements. This could be class, id, value, href etc.

`*` is the wildcard selector

if you target `*` you're targeting everything within the document. Within this context you are targeting all anchors whose href includes the string 'video'.

The syntax looks crazy but it makes sense, it's a simple way to target every video link within your site.

Comment: So what does `a[ ]` in `$("a[href*='video']")` do? Does it just create an array?

Comment: good question, quite possibly. Though I think it's just the syntax, you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors